# Line Break and Extra Spaces Randomly Showing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, erb

I am working with Rails 5.2, ruby 2.4.1, and using the Postgres(PG) database. I am trying to set javascript variables to values that are in my database. I am successful on all of them except the first column called "name". For some reason two extra spaces are added before each name. Then it eventually throws an error on one of them saying invalid or unexpected token. When it throws an error the code looks like it inserts a line break.

```
fullName: '
Chase  Dougherty',
firmName: 'Chase Bank', etc...
```

everyone before it looks like

```
fullName: '  Example Name',
firmName: 'Example Bank'. etc...
```

My name column in my database is correct because I can click "show" on each row and there are no extra spaces.

If I delete the info.name everything else works. If I remove the equal sign from inside the erb tags it works, but my javascript variable will be holding nothing(obviously).This error happens on load up. Does anyone have some ideas I can test out to fix this problem? Here is my code in case you want to test it out.

```
<script>

setContents = function setsPostgresDatatoJavascriptVariables(){

<% collective.each do |info| %>
typeMarkers = [
  {
    fullName: '<%= info.name %>',
    firmName:'<b><%= info.firm_name %></b>',
    firmNumber:'<b><%= info.firm_number %></b>',
    adjustmentType:'<b><%= info.adjustment_type %></b>',
    address:'<%= info.address_1 %>',
  },
];
<% end %>
}

<script>
```

Comment: "My name column in my database is correct because ..." On the show page, your browser will condense whitespace when it renders it.  You should do a view source, which will show any whitespace.  Check that and let me know if the name shows any new lines there.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into. I have to run to a meeting real quick, but will be right back.

Comment: Yeah I think it depends on the type of whitespace entered. If the whitespace is a user entered character, it could be any number of unicode whitespace characters (including breaking whitespace). You could try doing something like this `info.name.chars.map(&:ord)` to see what kind of whitespace it is, and then see about removing it via some method on the model.

Comment: @MarlinPierce and Matthew The problem was with the whitespace from the user. Marlin, you were right about it not showing up in the show page unless I viewed the source from the browser. I used the strip method in my model to clear up that extra space on the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My name column in my database is correct because ..."

On the show page, your browser will condense whitespace when it renders it. You should do a view source, which will show any whitespace.

If you see the leading whitespace there, then the leading whitespace is in your database.  You might call `strip()` to remove it.